Cannot run Mikro-ORM migrations on bun
I'm currently running an all-typescript project with Bun + Elysia. I've migrated my app from a previous NestJs project, which was running MikroORM just fine. Now that I've had my app running via bun, the migrator doesn't work:
bunx --bun mikro-orm

with the following error:
354 |         /* istanbul ignore next */
355 |         if ('type' in this.options) {
356 |             throw new Error('The `type` option has been removed in v6, please fill in the `driver` option instead or use `defineConfig` helper (to define your ORM config) or `MikroORM` class (to call the `init` method) exported from the driver package (e.g. `import { defineConfig } from \'@mikro-orm/mysql\'; export default defineConfig({ ... })`).');
357 |         }
358 |         if (!this.options.driver) {
359 |             throw new Error('No driver specified, please fill in the `driver` option or use `defineConfig` helper (to define your ORM config) or `MikroORM` class (to call the `init` method) exported from the driver package (e.g. `import { defineConfig } from \'@mikro-orm/mysql\'; export defineConfig({ ... })`).');
                        ^
error: No driver specified, please fill in the `driver` option or use `defineConfig` helper (to define your ORM config) or `MikroORM` class (to call the `init` method) exported from the driver package (e.g. `import { defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/mysql'; export defineConfig({ ... })`).
      at validateOptions (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\utils\Configuration.js:359:19)
      at new Configuration (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\utils\Configuration.js:140:13)
      at C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\utils\ConfigurationLoader.js:38:24  

error: script "orm" exited with code 1

But I've specified everything in src/orm.ts file properly like this:
// orm.ts
import { Migrator } from '@mikro-orm/migrations'
import { SeedManager } from '@mikro-orm/seeder'

import { MikroORM, ReflectMetadataProvider, SqliteDriver, defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/sqlite'
import { User } from '#user/user.entity'
import { Role } from '#role/role.entity'
import { Ability } from '#role/ability.entity'
import { Link } from '#link/link.entity'

export const config = defineConfig({
    debug: true,
    dbName: 'smm.db',
    driver: SqliteDriver,

    entities: [
        Role,
        Ability,
        User,
        Link
    ],

    extensions: [Migrator, SeedManager],
    migrations: {
        path: './src/data/migrations',
        transactional: true,
        emit: 'ts',
        snapshot: true
    },
    seeder: {
        path: './src/**/',
        glob: '!(*.d)(*.seeder).{js,ts}',
        emit: 'ts',
        defaultSeeder: 'DatabaseSeeder'
    },
    metadataProvider: ReflectMetadataProvider
})

export const orm = MikroORM.initSync(config)

export default orm


I'm running the orm with this command:
"orm": "bunx --bun mikro-orm"

This is the package.json file. Note that I do not wanna compile and produce js files:
"name": "smm_server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "module": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "bun run --watch src/index.ts",
    "inspect": "bun --inspect src/index.ts",
    "format": "biome format .",
    "lint": "biome lint .",
    "check": "biome check --apply .",
    "test": "bun test",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit --project tsconfig.json",
    "orm": "bunx --bun mikro-orm"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@elysiajs/cors": "1.0.2",
    "@elysiajs/eden": "1.0.14",
    "@elysiajs/jwt": "^1.0.2",
    "@elysiajs/static": "1.0.3",
    "@elysiajs/swagger": "1.0.5",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.4.1",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^6.2.9",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^6.2.9",
    "@mikro-orm/mysql": "^6.2.9",
    "@mikro-orm/reflection": "^6.2.9",
    "@mikro-orm/seeder": "^6.2.9",
    "@mikro-orm/sqlite": "^6.2.9",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "elysia": "1.0.22",
    "elysia-autoroutes": "0.5.0",
    "pino": "9.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@biomejs/biome": "1.7.3",
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^6.2.9",
    "bun-types": "1.1.10",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "alwaysAllowTs": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/data/orm.ts"
    ]
  },
  "trustedDependencies": [
    "sqlite3"
  ]
}

Also the tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Enable latest features
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,

    // Bundler mode
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    // Best practices
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["bun-types"],

    // Some stricter flags
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "#auth/*": ["./src/auth/*"],
      "#data/*": ["./src/data/*"],
      "#health/*": ["./src/health/*"],
      "#link/*": ["./src/link/*"],
      "#page/*": ["./src/page/*"],
      "#role/*": ["./src/role/*"],
      "#user/*": ["./src/user/*"],
      "#logger": ["./src/logger.ts"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}

I'm also adding two of these entities here:
import { Link } from '#link/link.entity'
import { Role, RoleStandard } from '#role/role.entity'

import { BeforeCreate, BeforeUpdate, Collection, Entity, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryKey, Property } from '@mikro-orm/core'

import { v4 } from 'uuid'

const SALT_ROUNDS = 10

@Entity({
    tableName: 'users'
})
export class User {
    @PrimaryKey({
        name: 'uuid',
        type: 'text',
        autoincrement: false,
        nullable: false,
        unique: true,
        comment: 'User\'s ID',
    })
    public uuid?: string = v4()

    @Property({
        name: 'username',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 32,
        unique: true,
        nullable: false,
        comment: 'User\'s username'
    })
    public username?: string

    @Property({
        name: 'email',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 64,
        unique: true,
        nullable: false,
        comment: 'User\'s email'
    })
    public email?: string

    @Property({
        name: 'display_name',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 32,
        nullable: true,
        comment: 'User\'s display name'
    })
    public display_name?: string | null

    @Property({
        name: 'password',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 64,
        nullable: false,
        comment: 'User\'s password'
    })
    public password?: string

    @Property({
        name: 'coins',
        type: 'integer',
        unsigned: true,
        nullable: false,
        default: 0,
        comment: 'User\'s coins'
    })
    public coins?: number

    @Property({
        name: 'created_at',
        type: 'datetime',
        nullable: false,
        comment: 'User\'s creation date and time'
    })
    public createdAt?: Date = new Date()

    /**
     * Updated at
     */
    @Property({
        name: 'updated_at',
        type: 'datetime',
        nullable: false,
        onUpdate: () => new Date(),
        comment: 'User\'s update date and time'
    })
    public updatedAt?: Date = new Date()

    @ManyToOne({
        entity: () => Role,
        nullable: false,
        deleteRule: 'set null',
    })
    public role?: Role

    @OneToMany({
        entity: () => Link,
        mappedBy: link => link.user,
        orphanRemoval: false
    })
    public links? = new Collection<Link>(this)

    @BeforeCreate()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    async hashPassword() {
        if (this.password) {
            this.password = await Bun.password.hash(this.password, {
                algorithm: 'bcrypt',
                cost: SALT_ROUNDS
            })
        }
    }

    @BeforeCreate()
    async setDefaultRole() {
        if (!this.role) {
            this.role = RoleStandard
        }
    }
}

And role.entity.ts:
import { User } from '#user/user.entity'

import { Collection, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryKey, Property } from '@mikro-orm/core'
import { Ability } from '#role/ability.entity'

@Entity({
    tableName: 'roles'
})
export class Role {
    constructor(id?: number, name?: string) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
    }

    @PrimaryKey({
        name: 'id',
        type: 'integer',
        autoincrement: false,
        comment: 'Role\'s ID',
    })
    public id?: number

    @Property({
        name: 'name',
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 16,
        unique: true,
        nullable: false,
        comment: 'Role\'s name'
    })
    public name?: string

    @OneToMany({
        entity: () => Ability,
        mappedBy: permission => permission.role,
        orphanRemoval: false
    })
    public abilities? = new Collection<Ability>(this)

    @OneToMany({
        entity: () => User,
        mappedBy: user => user.role,
        orphanRemoval: false
    })
    public users? = new Collection<User>(this)
}

export const RoleAdmin: Role = { id: 1, name: 'Admin' }
export const RolePremium: Role = { id: 2, name: 'Premium' }
export const RoleStandard: Role = { id: 3, name: 'Standard' }
export const RoleBanned: Role = { id: 4, name: 'Banned' }

Seriously I'm out of clues. When I use the orm command without MikroORM.init() (so just defineConfig()) it complains about all entities being abstract. So in the file orm.ts instead of exporting orm if I export config, it will output:
172 |     static noEntityDiscovered() {
173 |         return new MetadataError('No entities were discovered');
174 |     }
175 |     static onlyAbstractEntitiesDiscovered() {
176 |         return new MetadataError('Only abstract entities were discovered, maybe you forgot to use @Entity() decorator?');
177 |     }
                ^
MetadataError: Only abstract entities were discovered, maybe you forgot to use @Entity() decorator?
      at onlyAbstractEntitiesDiscovered (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\errors.js:177:11)
      at validateDiscovered (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataValidator.js:117:66)
      at findEntities (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:193:17)
      at C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:63:14 
      at discover (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\metadata\MetadataDiscovery.js:59:25)
      at C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\MikroORM.js:172:33
      at discoverEntities (C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\MikroORM.js:172:33)
      at C:\Users\X\Projects\smm_est\server\node_modules\@mikro-orm\cli\node_modules\@mikro-orm\core\MikroORM.js:80:13
      at processTicksAndRejections (native:1:1)

error: script "orm" exited with code 1

This thing has been getting on my nerve lately. I thought about moving to Drizzle, but with Mikro I have the ability to switch to MySql later easily.

I think your problem is not using default export for the ORM config. Don't mix your config with other stuff, especially with code with side effects like yours, that is a bad idea. Put the config separately, preferably to mikro-orm.config.ts file in the root (and don't forget to use default export), then it should just work.

Thanks. Moving the orm config to mikro-orm.config.ts to the root folder solved the issue. This still feels like a bug, using configPaths in package.json used to work fine in NestJs environment.

Tried again, still getting the error :(

It works just fine with bun too, your problem is not the location of the config file, but what (and how) the file exports. As mentioned in the GH discussion (next time please don't open the same report on multiple places, you won't get more attention because of that, in fact you only create more mess :]), you need to (default) export the ORM config and not the ORM instance.

You're right, I'm sorry. I'll update this after the issue is found.
